# Authentication System In Python using Tkinter

Tags: python, authentication, tkinter

I was curious about authentication systems in `python`. So I started building one with the help of the `tkinter` module. My authentication system works fine but I encountered a problem.

Here is the main page:

```
from tkinter import *
import SignIn.AccountsPage

if SignIn.AccountsPage.Access:
    # Initialising tkinter
    main = Tk()
    main.title("Home")
    main.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(main.winfo_screenwidth(), main.winfo_screenheight()))
    main.bind("<Escape>", lambda x: x.widget.geometry("400x200"))
    main.bind("<KeyPress-f>",
              lambda x: x.widget.geometry(
                  "{0}x{1}+0+0".format(main.winfo_screenwidth(), main.winfo_screenheight())))

    # Frames for widgets
    LeftFrame = LabelFrame(main, padx=100, pady=20)
    LeftFrame.place(x=0, y=0, height=main.winfo_screenheight(), width=(main.winfo_screenwidth() * 0.277))

    TopFrame = LabelFrame(main, padx=10, pady=10)
    TopFrame.place(x=main.winfo_screenwidth() * 0.277, y=0, height=(main.winfo_screenheight() / 2),
                   width=(main.winfo_screenwidth() - main.winfo_screenwidth() * 0.277))

    BottomFrame = LabelFrame(main, padx=10, pady=10)
    BottomFrame.place(x=main.winfo_screenwidth() * 0.277, y=main.winfo_screenheight() / 2,
                      height=(main.winfo_screenheight() / 2),
                      width=(main.winfo_screenwidth() - main.winfo_screenwidth() * 0.277))

    main.mainloop()
else:
    sys.exit()
```

Here is the login page:

```
from tkinter import *

from SignIn import LoginModule as LM, EncryptionModule as EM
from SignIn.LoginModule import CommonPassword

Access = False

# Creating Database
EM.CredentialSetUp()


# Initializing
root = Tk()
root.title("Login")

# Entry Widget
e = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=7)
e.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=4)

f = Entry(root, show='*', width=50, borderwidth=7)
f.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=4)


# Functions
def login():
    searchu = e.get()
    searchp = f.get()
    if LM.AlmostThere(searchu, searchp):
        root.destroy()
        logger.info("{} has logged in to Systaurant".format(searchu))
        return True

    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Login Denied", "Oops looks like you have entered a wrong username or password!")
        logger.info("{} has been denied access to Systaurant".format(searchu))
        return False

# Buttons and Labels
Username = Label(root, text="Username:")
Username.grid(row=0, column=0)

Password = Label(root, text="Password:")
Password.grid(row=2, column=0)

Login = Button(root, text="Login", command=login)
Login.grid(row=3, column=1)

Exit = Button(root, text="Quit", command=exit1)
Exit.grid(row=3, column=2)

root.bind('<Return>', lambda event=None: Login.invoke())
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda event=None: Exit.invoke())

if login:
    Access = True
else:
    Access = False

root.mainloop()
```

In the `AccountsPage.py` file:

So basically, what's happening here is that the user enters his/her username and password in the `entry` widgets. Then the `login()` function checks if its valid or not. And if the `login()` is `False` then `Access = False` and if `login()` is `True` then `Access = True`.

Then in the `main.py` file:

If `Access = True` then the frames get displayed.
Otherwise `sys.exit()` is invoked.

The system works fine if used properly but I discovered a bug.

If the `AccountsPage.py` is closed by pressing on the close button or `Alt-f4`, the `main.py` automatically opens without any authentication. Any suggestions on how to tackle this issue?

Comment: You could try `root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",  func1)`. This runs `func1` when the window is closed.

Comment: Sure let me take a look at that method. Just to clarify, on which line do you put this statement?